# 'removeLastObject ' out of bounds error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have an NSMutableArray named lineStore, When I run:

```
[lineStore removeLastItem]
```

I get the error

```
'NSRangeException'....index 92 beyond bounds [0..90]
```

Where the index is 2 beyond its' bound. Not a major issue, obviously I can just use 'removeObjectAtIndex' method. The question is why is this method doing this, is there something I've missed in the documentation. This method *sounds* straightforward and all the other NSMutableArray methods seem to work in an intuitive manner.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing any sort of multithreading, whether explicitly or via GCD? (and, presumably, you mean `removeLastObject`)

Comment: As per NSMutableArray Class reference `removeLastObject raises an NSRangeException if there are no objects in the array.` Try this `NSLog(@"Array %@ and count %d",lineStore,[lineStore count]);`before sending removeLastItem message to lineStore array.

Comment: Well there was definitely objects in the lineStore Array. Thanks for that tip because after I ran your suggested command, everything runs as expected even after being commented out. I didn't change anything else. Odd.